# Play 2 not able to find xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar failed download

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I just started working with Play 2 and Heroku, but when I tried to deployed the application I got an error.  I tried doing an sbt clean compile and this is what I got:

```
Marcelos-MacBook-Pro:guzmanenergy marcelo$ sbt clean compile
Marcelos-MacBook-Pro:guzmanenergy marcelo$ sbt clean compile
[info] Loading project definition from /projects/guzmanenergy/project
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2!xml-apis.jar (146ms)
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2!xml-apis.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/projects/guzmanenergy/project/}default-de2d7b/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: xml-apis#xml-apis;1.0.b2!xml-apis.ja
```

Comment: Same here, whats weird is that there is nothing in that repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/xml-apis/ , however in this other repo the jars are present: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/ I tried adding them but cant manage to do it

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the line

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo1/"
```

to your project/plugins.sbt file. Make sure there is a white line between every line, check the [guide](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Basic-Def.html) for more info

Comment: I changed it.  Previously, it was: "resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"I get the following error now: "FAILED DOWNLOADS" org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.1!slf4j-api.jar.

Comment: fairly strange. I must have the jars locally cause don't get that error. Could you try just adding the line above instead of replacing it with the releases repository?

Comment: That did it! I changed my project/plugins.sbt to the following: `// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo1/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")` and now I am able to rung the `gtd clean compile` and I was able to export to heroku! #win