# Error with Play 2.0 Scala

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0, deadbolt

When trying to run some of the Scala samples using Play2 ([zentasks](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/zentasks)) I get the following errors:

```
==== Maven Central: tried

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt_2.9.1/0.12.0/sbt_2.9.1-0.12.0.pom

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: org.scala-sbt#sbt_2.9.1;0.12.0: not found

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I have checked the following:

1. sbt version = 0.12.1
2. scala = 2.9.2
3. jvm = 1.6.0_37
4. play 2.0.4

My project/build.properties is the following:

```
sbt.version=0.11.3
```

I've changed sbt version to 0.12.1; however, it seems that Play2 (this version) runs its own Scala and sbt version. 
My project/plugins.sbt is:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo1/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.0.4")
```

I am able to create a "new" project (working in prod) without any issues, but I can't run any of the samples.  I also tried it on some others projects ([deadbolt2](https://github.com/schaloner/deadbolt-2-scala-examples)) and had the same issue.

Comment: What is this second "resolvers" in your `plugins.sbt` file ?

Comment: This I got from @mericano1 when he answered [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14716830/498555)

Comment: I was able to run the [zentasks](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/scala/zentasks) project by downloading and installing the latest [play2.1](http://www.playframework.com/download) and using sbt 0.12.1

Comment: It seems that the s3 repositories that heroku uses are not very reliable. I have frequently run builds that crap out with different unresolved dependencies on subsequent builds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.11.3 when running existing project in Play 2.1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989154/error-could-not-retrieve-sbt-0-11-3-when-running-existing-project-in-play-2-1-0)